# apply two callbacks for single dynamic matrix

Tags: matlab

**Display**

```
G3.vardisp= uicontrol('Style','edit',...
           'Position', [520 280 30 30],...
           'String','0');
```

**Slider**

```
G3.slide = uicontrol('style','slide',...
                 'unit','pix',...
                 'position',[400 280 120 30],...
                 'min',-10,'max',10,'val',1,...
                 'sliderstep',[1/20 1/10],...
                 'callback',{@sl_call3,G3});
```

**callback for Slider**

```
function [] = sl_call3(varargin)
 [l,G3] = varargin{[1,3]};  % calling handle and data structure.
 set(G3.vardisp,'String',get(l,'value'))
 vbrilho=get(l,'value')
 subplot('Position',[.35, 0.575, 0.375, 0.375])
 x4.head_mod=(vcontraste*x4.head)+(vbrilho*10);
 imshow(x4.head_mod)
end
```

**button**

```
 filtro.medfiltbtn1 = uicontrol('Parent',hsp,...
                'Style', 'pushbutton',...
                'String', 'medfilt2_1',...
                'Position',[0 35 80 30],...
                'callback',{@teste,1});
```

**callback for button**

```
function []= teste(varargin)

[t1] = varargin{[3]};
while t1==1
    subplot('Position',[.35, 0.575, 0.375, 0.375])
    x4.head_modf=imnoise(x4.head_mod,'gaussian',0,0.01);
    t1=0;
    imshow(x4.head_modf)
end
```

When the code is run the `imnoise` can be applied over the `x4.head_mod`, but I can't apply the equation `(vcontraste*x4.head)+(vbrilho*10)` over `imnoise`. I want somehow to nest both results.

Comment: What does _apply the equation (vcontraste*x4.head)+(vbrilho*10) over imnoise_ mean? How / where `x4` is defined and managed?

Comment: x4.head is an image (matrix), vbrilho and vcontraste are two variables from sliders. A numeric example:

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.